# How do I view Security Group rules for an AWS EC2 Security Group using the command-line tools?

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, port-forwarding

I know that you can set Security Group rules with `ec2-authorize` and `ec2-revoke`. How do you view the rules of a given security group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All commands available within the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351) are documented in the [Amazon EC2 Command Line Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/Welcome.html?r=8650) - informational commands usually follow the *ec2-describe-** pattern, and the one you are looking for is [ec2-describe-group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2012-04-01/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSecurityGroups.html):

> Returns information about security groups in your account. This
>   includes both EC2 security groups and VPC security groups. For
>   information about how the two types of groups differ, go to [Security
>   Groups](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) in the Amazon Virtual Private Cloud User Guide.

Comment: hi Steffen, would you provide a full command-line example, including which environment variables to specify?

Answer (score 1):

```
~$ ec2-describe-group |grep GROUP
```

will show the list of all security groups

```
~$ ec2-describe-group |grep GROUP|cut -f4
```

to get only security groups names

```
~$ ec2-describe-group|grep <YOUR_GROUP_NAME>
```

to get the policies for that sec group